# Who is Mudallis narrator ? Is the narrator "Nafi Bin Mehmood Bin Al-rabi Al-Ansari " is Mudallis?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal

My Question is basically on a hadith of **" Sunan Abi Dawood " ( سنن ابی داؤد ) Hadith No. 824**

Translation of Hadith : ([Abi Dawood 824](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:824))::

**"Nafib. Mahmudb. Al-Rabi Al-Ansari said: “Ubadah bin al-Samit came to late to lead the morning prayer. Abu Nuaim, the Muadhdhin, pronounced the takbir and he led the people in prayer. Then Ubadah came and I was with him. We Joined the row behind Abu Nuaim, while Abu Nuaim was reciting the Quran loudly. Then Ubadah began to recite the Umm al-Quran (I. e Surah al Fatihah). When he finished, I said to Ubadah: I heard you reciting the Umm al-Quran while Abu Nuaim was reciting Quran loudly. He replied: yes> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ led us in a certain prayer in which the Quran is recited loudly, but he became confused in the recitation. When he finished he turned his face to us and said: Do you recite when I recite the Quran loudly? Some of us said: we do so; this is why I said to myself: What is that which confused me (in the recitation of ) the Quran. Do not recite anything from the Quran when I recite it loudly except the Umm al-Quran."**

Is The Narrator of this Hadith is Mudallis?? As a Mufti said to me that this Hadith is not sahih as the narrator of this hadith is Mudallis and he gives the reference from the book **"Tabqaat al Mudaliseen"** written Imam ibn Hajar al-Asqalani . He (Mufti) Said **Imam ibn Hajar al-Asqalani** mention that **Nafay bin Mehmood Al-Rabi Al-Ansari**  is Mudallis..

I tried to find the book **"Tabqaat al Mudaliseen"** But I am fail to find that book... I am confused about this Hadith as many "Muhadiseen" Said this hadith Sahih...

Comment: One part of your question is addressed in [What exactly is tadlees?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46975/what-exactly-is-tadless). The book of ibn Hajar is available online طبقات المدلسين. These kinds of questions require research effort, time or better knowledge about the topic.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Ok.. But what about Nafay bin Mehmood Al-Rabi Al-Ansari?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Sir plz share the link so i can download the book...

Comment: Well I'm speaking about the Arabic original -not a translation-: just type the title in google and you will find several resources online and also for download. But if you are not familiar with the use it could be somewhat time consuming. Maybe you won't even find him in ibn Hajar's book as he regard him as hidden (See [here](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/7860/%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B9-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9))  which means he knows him, but can't give a qualification. Note that al-Albani qualified the hadith as da'if.

Comment: Please add all important information to your posts. Comments are meant for clarification purposes and not meant to last forever and can be deleetd on regular basis.